# React duplicates SVG when using them as an Element in an array of object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I'm writing a code in React that use an array of object to pass them as the props of a component.

This object has an attribute called image that takes a JSX element, imported from a SVG file.

```
import { ReactComponent as SomeSvg1 } from 'assets/images/svg/Home/some_svg1.svg'
import { ReactComponent as SomeSvg2 } from 'assets/images/svg/Home/some_svg2.svg'
import { ReactComponent as SomeSvg3 } from 'assets/images/svg/Home/some_svg3.svg'

export const SVG_OBJECTS = [
  {
    target: 'sometarget1',
    image: <SomeSvg1 />
  },
  {
    target: 'sometarget2',
    image: <SomeSvg2 />
  },
  {
    target: 'sometarget3',
    image: <SomeSvg3 />
  }
]
```

Then I use it in a component:

```
const SomeContainer = () => {
  return (
    <Box>
      {SVG_OBJECTS.map((item) => {
        return (
          <SomeComponent
            {...item}
            key={item.target}
          />
        )
      })}
    </Box>
  )
}
```

But as a result I get the exactly same images for the 3 components rendered.

The SVG are differents, when I change the order (for example I use `<SomeSvg2 />` instead of `<SomeSvg1 />`) the `<SomeSvg2 />` get displayed.

I hope it's clear and that you can help me.

Edit: I tried to render without using map, but I get the same result

```
const SomeContainer = () => {
  return (
    <Box>
      <SomeComponent {...SVG_OBJECTS[0]} image={<SomeSvg1 />} />
      <SomeComponent {...SVG_OBJECTS[1]} image={<SomeSvg2 />} />
      <SomeComponent {...SVG_OBJECTS[2]} image={<SomeSvg3 />} />
    </Box>
  )
}
```

Comment: Try to use img tag. Import your svg and put it in img src.

Comment: You probably have duplicate id values between the images.